# Multiple ResultSets, different queries, same database SQLSERVER

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Using JDBC driver, how can I use multiple result sets from different queries without continually opening and closing the connections, as it stand im extracting w.e I need and passing it to another method. Each time opening a new conn,statement and resultset

```
public static void OppQuery() {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result_set = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String emailInfoQuery = "FROM WHERE";
}


public static void addQuery(String latestRenewalId) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result_set = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String new_AddressLine1, new_AddressLine2;
        new_AddressLine1=new_AddressLine2="";
        int new_ChannelOption= 0;
}
```

I tried to use multiple result sets in one method but it kept throwing exceptions saying the result set was closed. I don't have much experience with SqlServver so any guidance would help :-)

Comment: Your current code doesn't have the problem you describe (but it seems to be incomplete as well)

Comment: I wanted to know can I avoid this and combine into one method without separating all with one connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JDBC, when the connection is in auto-commit mode (which is the default), any execution of a statement will commit the previous transaction and close any open result sets on the same connection (assuming the holdability is `ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT`, which actually [isn't the default for SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378765.aspx)). When you need to have multiple result sets open, you need to have auto-commit disabled (or use `ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT`) **and** you need to use multiple `Statement` objects. JDBC requires that a new execute on the same `Statement` object closes any other open result sets from that same statement.

So

1. Disable auto-commit (`Connection.setAutoCommit(false)`)
2. Use multiple `Statement` objects to open the `ResultSet`s

Comment: I understand why multiple `Statement` objects are necessary, but I'm not so sure about the auto-commit requirement. Look [here](http://pastebin.com/BJ83DhHP).

Comment: The specification (chapter 10) says: "Typically, a new transaction is started when the current SQL statement requires one and there is
no transaction already in place. [...] Enabling auto-commit causes a transaction commit after each individual SQL statement as soon as that statement is complete". JDBC has a 'single transaction per connection' model, so if a transaction is started with the execute of a `Statement`, that implies the previous transaction will be committed (or rolled back) and therefor any open `ResultSet` will be closed (except for holdable `ResultSet`s).

Comment: @GordThompson It looks like the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver uses holdable `ResultSet`s by default, see [Using Holdability](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378765.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Further to Mark's answer, since the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver seems to create "Holdable" ResultSet objects by default, the following test code does work when AutoCommit is enabled:

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class SqlServerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String connectionUrl =
                    "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:52865;" +
                    "databaseName=myDb;" +
                    "integratedSecurity=true";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            System.out.println(String.format("con.getAutoCommit returned %s", con.getAutoCommit()));

            Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM odds");
            rs1.next();
            System.out.println(String.format("value from rs1: %d", rs1.getInt(1)));

            Statement st2 = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM evens");
            rs2.next();
            System.out.println(String.format("value from rs2: %d", rs2.getInt(1)));

            rs1.next();
            System.out.println(String.format("value from rs1: %d", rs1.getInt(1)));

            rs2.next();
            System.out.println(String.format("value from rs2: %d", rs2.getInt(1)));

            rs2.close();
            rs1.close();
            con.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

For test data in tables named [odds]...

```
id  description
--  -----------
 1  one
 3  three
 5  five
```

...and [evens]...

```
id  description
--  -----------
 2  two
 4  four
 6  six
```

...the console output is:

```
con.getAutoCommit returned true
value from rs1: 1
value from rs2: 2
value from rs1: 3
value from rs2: 4
```